# Arduino analog in with 12v

Tags: arduino, maximum-ratings

I have a circuit like [this](https://github.com/jath03/science-fair/blob/master/Science%20fair%20diagram.png) that has a 12vDC power supply.  I would like to measure the voltage on either side of each of the lights with the arduino's analog input pins, but the arduino's max voltage is 5v.

How would I keep the voltage at least proportional to its value while making it less than 5v?

Normally to read voltage from the arduino, I would get the value, which is a number in between 0 and 1023, then multiply it by 5/1023 to give me a voltage between 0 and 5 volts.  Could I just stick a resistor between the point on the circuit and the arduino, then multiply the value from the input by 12/1023?

Comment: This site has a built in schematic tool (Crtl-M). For future reference. =-D

Comment: Ok thanks, new to the electronics site.  I'm usually more of a software guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to measure the voltage on either side of each of the
>   lights with the arduino's analog input pins, but the arduino's max
>   voltage is 5v.

To linearly reduce a higher voltage to a lower voltage requires a resistor potential divider like this: -

[image]

So if the bottom resistor is (say) 5 kohms and the top resistor is (say) 7 kohms then 12 volts in becomes 5 volts out but, you might want to give a little headroom so that 15 volts in becomes 5 volts out. so use a 5 kohm for Rbottom and a 10 kohm for Rtop.

I would also be tempted to put 100 nF across the lower resistor so that the ADC sampling operates accurately.

Comment: But the each light needs the full 12 volts, will this keep the voltage the same for the lights?

Comment: The resistors will not affect the lights I.e. the resistors will not steal significant energy.

Comment: LOL this was for a science fair project and I just realized that I don't need that value.  Thanks anyway for future reference though.